# Neo4j - convert specific paths into a new relationship

Tags: neo4j

I'm using StackOverflow data which can be represented like so:

`(user)-[:ASKED]->(question)` and

`(user)-[:PROVIDED]->(answer)` and

`(answer)-[:IN_RESPONSE_TO]->(question)`

When 1 user responds to another's question, I was to create a new relationship called `[:INTERACTS_WITH]`, so the below path:

`(user_A)-[:ASKED]->(question)<-[:IN_RESPONSE_TO]-(answer)<-[:PROVIDED]-(user_B)`

Will become:
`(user_A)-[:INTERACTS_WITH]-(user_B)`

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Many thanks!

P.S. sorry if this is a silly question, I'm new to Neo4j and I'm not even sure what's the best way to search for the answer on the web for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
MATCH (user_A)-[:ASKED]->(question)<-[:IN_RESPONSE_TO]-(answer)<-[:PROVIDED]-(user_B)
MERGE (user_A)-[:INTERACTS_WITH]-(user_B)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I can't even build a query that would return any valid results based on `(user_A)-[:ASKED]->(question)<-[:IN_RESPONSE_TO]-(answer)<-[:PROVIDED]-(user_B)` which I intended to be used as a pseudo-query to explain the structure. I tried this `match (user)-[:ASKED|PROVIDED|IN_RESPONSE_TO*]-(user) merge (user)-[:INTERACTS_WITH]-(user)` but it didn't work, it created loops around the answer nodes.

Comment: yea obviously... change first match `match (user1)-[:ASKED|PROVIDED|IN_RESPONSE_TO*]-(user2) merge (user1)-[:INTERACTS_WITH]-(user2)`

Comment: Thanks, this is closer, but not there yet. That seems to create `INTERACTS_WITH` relationships with all nodes, not just users (as well as loops where origin and destination is the same node). Am I missing something? Sorry, I'm new to Neo4j.

Comment: Got it!

match (user1:User)-[:ASKED]-(:Question)-[:IN_RESPONSE_TO]-(:Answer)-[:PROVIDED]-(user2:User)
merge (user1)-[:INTERACTS_WITH]-(user2)

Thanks!